# What does it mean by PSU (1,1) in the context of complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, notation, complex-geometry

I see in some notes the notation $\text{PSU}(1,1).$ The author say that this is the automorphism group of the unit disc on the complex plane.

But I do not know where $(1,1)$ comes from. One of the $1$ might be the dimension, but what about the other $1$?

Are there any reasonable guesses?

Comment: The $(1,1)$ refers to the signature of the metric: It is the analogue of $\mathrm{PSU}(2)$, the (standard) group of projective unitary $2 \times 2$-matrices, except that unitarity is now with respect to a metric of the form diag$(-1, 1)$.

Comment: @SebastianSchulz So it is the group of transformations that preserves the $(-1,1)$ metric (a bit like the Lorentz invariant interval) and has determinant 1?

Comment: It is the quotient of $SU(1,1)$ by its center.

Comment: @Ma Joad that's correct (after taking the quotient by its center), and yes it is very much like the Lorentz group, which is a connected component of the group SO(3,1)